# What kind of parser is a pratt parser?

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, pratt-parser

I'm implementing pratt's [top down operator precedence](http://javascript.crockford.com/tdop/tdop.html) parser and I'd like to know in which formal category it falls into - is it LR(1)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pratt parser are not LR parsers. And they're not exactly LL parsers either. In fact, Pratt parsers are generally hand-coded in some general purpose programming language; the technique is not based on an abstraction like push-down finite state automata. This makes it somewhat more difficult to prove assertions about a given Pratt parser, such as that it recognizes a particular formal language.

In general, Pratt parsers can easily be designed to recognize a language if the grammar is an operator precedence grammar, so they can be considered to be a dual of operator precedence parsing, even though operator precedence parsing is bottom-up and Pratt parsers are nominally top-down. Tracing a Pratt parser and the transitions of an operator precedence parser for the same language will show the similarity.

So I suppose that it might be possible to come up with a formalism for Pratt parsers, but as far as I know, none exists.

Comment: Pratt parsers are bottom up operator precedence parsers that use the call stack instead of an array as their stack. The thing that makes people think that they are top down is that they can easily be interleaved with a top-down recursive descent parser, unlike LR parsers. You can extend LL(1) grammars to include embedded pratt parsers by allowing left self-recursive rules (with precedence) where the first non-self token is a nonterminal that does not conflict with the follow set computed from the other rules

Comment: The main reason why undergrad language grammar textbooks can't cover this well is that the most natural automaton model to use here is the nested stack automaton, not plain pushdown automata.